# Using Number formater java

Tags: java, android, numbers, rounding, number-formatting

I am try to use number formatter in java to formart intiger in to compact number fomart like 1000 to 1k but it give error
My code

```
package com.project.newproject;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
NumberFormat formatter =  NumberFormat.getCompactNumberInstance( Locale.US,NumberFormat.Style.SHORT);

    }
```

How to fix the error:
**Style** cannot be resolved or is not a field

How to fix issue Style cannot be resolved.

Comment: `NumberFormat.Style` was introduced in java 12. I guess you use a older version

Comment: but  `getCompactNumberInstance` is also not available before Java 12 ....

Comment: Probably your Android API level is not compatible with [Java-12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.Style.html).  Check [this](https://ideone.com/OQhUpi).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, try using  this, it will solve your problem

```
    public static String formatValue(float value) {
      String arr[] = {"", "K", "M", "B", "T", "P", "E"};
      int index = 0;
      while ((value / 1000) >= 1) {
          value = value / 1000;
          index++;
      }
      DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
      return String.format("%s %s", decimalFormat.format(value), arr[index]);
    }
```